# A Tale of Wintry Tragedy

Tags: rhyme, situation

$$\def\T{\text}\scriptsize{\begin{array}
\\\T{`Twas weather chilly in winter's dark} & \T{Absconded with them far away}
\\\T{When brothers five went out to lark} & \T{Made a mistake they could not repay}
\\\T{They braved the ice, cold, and snow} & \T{For when the sisters all awoke}
\\\T{And found a dwelling all aglow} & \T{Five brothers each poor heart broke}
\\\T{There they met by happenstance} & \T{As sisters five they all went wan}
\\\T{Five sisters up in fiery dance} & \T{Crumpled dead, each one was gone}
\\\T{All entwined in passion's embrace} & \T{Soon brothers followed, empty inside}
\\\T{They kissed each brother on the face} & \T{From guilt nor sorrow could they hide}
\\\T{Alas! Oh, that fleeting scene} & \T{And thus I do report to thee}
\\\T{Star-crossed lovers that convene} & \T{A Tale of Wintry Tragedy}
\\\T{Destined to happen, yet not to last} & \T{But fear not for the legends write}
\\\T{For their ends were approaching fast} & \T{That come another wintry night}
\\\T{Fortune went to the brothers' heads} & \T{Those lovers of greatest romance}
\\\T{They took the sisters from their beds} & \T{May rise up for a second chance}\end{array}}$$

<sup>$$\scriptsize{\T{Explain.}}$$</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New answer is

> 5 Brothers are the fingers of a glove

and

> 5 Sisters are the fingers of a battery powered heated glove liner

Because

`Twas weather chilly in winter's dark
When brothers five went out to lark

> Winter gloves needed for cold weather

They braved the ice, cold, and snow
And found a dwelling all aglow

> The glove was taken inside

There they met by happenstance
Five sisters up in fiery dance

> The heated glove liner was plugged in charging

All entwined in passion's embrace
They kissed each brother on the face

> The glove was put on the smaller glove liner

Alas! Oh, that fleeting scene
Star-crossed lovers that convene
Destined to happen, yet not to last
For their ends were approaching fast

> A glove is only needed in the cold. Not needed at all times.

Fortune went to the brothers' heads
They took the sisters from their beds

> The glove liner was unplugged

Absconded with them far away
Made a mistake they could not repay

> The glove could not power the heated glove liner

For when the sisters all awoke
Five brothers each poor heart broke

> The next morning after the glove warmer was used up

As sisters five they all went wan
Crumpled dead, each one was gone

> The glove warmer ran out of warmth

Soon brothers followed, empty inside
From guilt nor sorrow could they hide

> No more warmth. Empty inside

And thus I do report to thee
A Tale of Wintry Tragedy
But fear not for the legends write
That come another wintry night
Those lovers of greatest romance
May rise up for a second chance

> A glove will be needed to cover fingers again on another wintry day. Plug the glove warmer back in to charge the battery again

Thoughts

> I am not familiar with a heated glove liner, but they do exist. This does sound like a stretch. However, it does seem to make sense.

Previous

> Brothers are fingers of a glove (OP said I was right about the brothers)
>  Sisters are fingers on a hand (not correct)

Comment: rot13(Lbh'er evtug nobhg gur oebguref, ohg abg nobhg gur fvfgref)

Comment: Fb, ba gur arkg jvagel avtug, Qb gur rknpg fnzr oebguref naq fvfgref zrrg? Be qbrf gur 'fpranevb' unccra ntnva jvgu qvssrerag cynlref?

Comment: rot13(Gur rknpg fnzr cnvef zrrg ntnva.)

Comment: rot13(Gung'f evtug! V yrnearq nobhg urngrq tybir yvaref gbqnl orpnhfr zl unaqf jrer fgvyy pbyq rira jvgu gur tybirf, fb V svtherq V'q znxr n chmmyr bhg bs vg :))

Comment: rot13(V jnf whfg guvaxvat nobhg jevgvat, " Jbj, V qvqa'g rira xabj gubfr rkvfgrq. Fjrrg." :)) LOL - This puzzle is quite skillfully done. Nice work.